# Some example using SubProtocolWebSocketHandler and stompSubProtocolHandler?

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs, spring-messaging

I can't find examples of use of stompSubProtocolHandler and SubProtocolWebSocketHandler?

I need extend this SubProtocolWebSocketHandler class?

```
private static class ProducerStompSessionHandler2 extends SubProtocolWebSocketHandler {

        public ProducerStompSessionHandler2(MessageChannel clientInboundChannel,
                SubscribableChannel clientOutboundChannel) {
            super(clientInboundChannel, clientOutboundChannel);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }


    }
```

I'm using a handler for a Sockjs java client that extend of StompSessionHandlerAdapter and is working. I can connect, subscribe and send messages:

private static class ProducerStompSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {
     ...

}

But I see another user telling that there are two implementacions: SubProtocolWebSocketHandler and stompSubProtocolHandler.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28306539/6243317

These are implementation of Java Websocket over STOMP clients? how use? advantages? why use this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question in the title, I think [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/stomp-chat) sample by Spring would be useful to you. The stompSubProtocolHandler is more server side in the sample, but I assume the logic will be the same for client.

Comment: No, this is nowhere related to what was being asked and is not helpful at all.